# dynamic generation of views in mvc based on parameter id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity

This is one of method inside my controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Ajax(string AJAXParameter1)
{     
    List<string> data = new List<string>();
    data.Add("AJAXParameter1=" + AJAXParameter1);
    return Json(new { data, result = "OK" });
}
```

If parameter AJAXParameter1 recieves value as passport i want to display view that contains fileds related to passport. If it recieves value as pan i want to render some different view that allow us to add pan card related details. For pan and passport i have models. Based on Id i want to generate view.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to do this is to simply create two views or partialviews based on how your application will have to look, one for the passport and one for the pan card.
Then in your controller method see which one you receive and return the view needed.

something like:

```
[HttpPost] public ActionResult ReturnNeeded(string Parameter1){  
    if (IsPassport(Parameter1)){  
        return View("PasswordView");
    }else if (IsPan(Parameter1)){
        return View("PanView");
    }
return View("OopsBadRequest");
}
```

maybe?

Comment: The method is Json so is there any other way yo handle this?

Comment: public JsonResult Ajax(string AJAXParameter1) Here i will be getting values to AjaxParameter1. From here depending on parameter i want to generate diferent different views based on parameter. Please tell me how to achieve this